# Connect-mongo not creating database

Tags: mongodb, express, session-storage

I have the following code to set up a session store with `connect-mong`

```
 var express = require('express');
 var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
 var app = express();

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
secret: '1234567890QWERTY',
maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
store: new MongoStore({
    db: 'mydb',
    host: '127.0.0.1'
}),
 cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }
}));
```

In the requests and responses from the server I can see the `sessionID`s, but the database is not created or if I create it the `session` collection does not gets filled. I do not receive any errors on the console.

I cannot find what am I missing ( using express 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multiple `use` of the session and `cookieParser`. This caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because nobody connected yet to your express server. So there's no session to store.

Add

```
app.listen(3000, function() {
        console.log('now listening  on http://localhost:3000/'); 
});
```

At the end and connect to the server in your browser. Immediately you will get sessions collections in your Mongo db.

Comment: Of course I started my server. Otherwise how could I see the cookie in the browser?

Comment: I just did it starting the server, I entered once to my webpage and it worked perfectly. Might be something in your installation? I tried also passing a Mongoose connection and it worked too.

Comment: Actually I found the problem just now. I've created the application through express's automatically and didn't check all the imports it made. It turns out that he instatiated the `cookieParser()` and `session` already. Then I did it again, that caused the problem. Thanks for verifying that the code worked.